# Keep gap between nested multiline columns with background

Tags: css, grid, bulma

I've created with Bulma nested multiline columns a grid with card styled entries. How can I keep the gap between the lines with a background color or rather how is the Bulma way to do this? Here you can find a prepared example:

https://codepen.io/teranovalp/pen/NWxaWJe

```
    <div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="columns is-multiline">
          <div class="column is-4">
            <div class="has-background-primary">
              <p>1</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column is-4">
            <div class="has-background-primary">
              <div class="columns is-multiline">
                <div class="column is-12">
                  <h1>2</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-6">
                  <h1>2.1</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-6">
                  <h1>2.2</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column is-4">
            <div class="has-background-primary">
              <p>3</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column is-4">
            <div class="has-background-primary">
              <p>4</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column is-4">
            <div class="has-background-primary">
              <div class="columns is-multiline">
                <div class="column is-12">
                  <h1>5</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-6">
                  <h1>5.1</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-6">
                  <h1>5.2</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column is-4">
            <div class="has-background-primary">
              <p>6</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

(There I want a similar gap between 2 and 5 as between the columns)

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you want a "white" gap between the columns 2, 2.1, 2.2 like you have between 1 or 2? Or you meant that you wanted a gap between 2 and 5 when they are rendered as separate rows?

Comment: @viam0Zah I see 2, 2.1 and 2.2 as a whole and I want a free space between the whole 2 and 5, as with the others without several lines. So that in the end it looks like a grid with equal spaces between all sides of the columns. Like this for example: https://imgur.com/a/ijGJ3E0

Answer (score 0):

For boxes 1, 3, 4, 6 you set the background color directly of the element *inside* the column. For 2, 6, you set the background color of the element that *wraps* the column. When you apply the background color to the wrapper element, it will also paint the padding of the column. That's why it looks as if there was no gap between 2 and 5.

I see two options to overcome this. Use the attribute `is-gapless` on the nested columns. However this way you also lose the padding between the nested children (2, 2.1, 2.2).

```html
<div class="column is-4">
  <div class="columns is-multiline is-gapless has-background-primary">
    <div class="column is-12">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    ...
```

Or consider switching to [tiles](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/tiles/) for your layout which is better suited for the job if you want to set a background color for each cell in the grid.